# Laravel - How to set zero as default in Log Activity if company_id doesn't exist

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8 User Log activity, I have this code:

```
public static function addToLog($subject, $logtype=null, $subjecthint=null)
{
    $log = [];
    $log['subject'] = $subject;
    $log['log_type'] = $logtype;
    $log['subject_hint'] = $subjecthint;
    $log['log_url'] = Request::fullUrl();
    $log['log_method'] = Request::method();
    $log['ip_address'] = Request::ip();
    $log['agent'] = Request::header('user-agent');
    $log['user_id'] = auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->id : 1;
    $log['company_id'] = auth()->user()->company_id;
    $log['created_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    LogActivityModel::create($log);
}
```

In $log['company_id'] = auth()->user()->company_id;

How do I make company_id = 0 When the logged in user doesn't belong to any company?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the approach you've taken in the line directly above? Or, more concisely, `$log['company_id'] = Auth::user()->company_id ?? 0;`

Comment: Note you may have foreign key issues using 0, in which case you could use null instead, assuming your migration is configured properly.

Comment: @miken32 - Please can you show me typical example on how to resolve it?

Answer (score -1):

if you want you can use one of those

`$log['company_id'] = auth()->check() ? (auth()->user()->company_id ?? 0) : 0;`

`$log['company_id'] = optioanl(auth()->user())->company_id ?? 0;`

```
public static function addToLog($subject, $logtype=null, $subjecthint=null)
{

    $log = [];
    $log['subject'] = $subject;
    $log['log_type'] = $logtype;
    $log['subject_hint'] = $subjecthint;
    $log['log_url'] = Request::fullUrl();
    $log['log_method'] = Request::method();
    $log['ip_address'] = Request::ip();
    $log['agent'] = Request::header('user-agent');
    $log['user_id'] = auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->id : 1;
    $log['company_id'] = auth()->check() ? (auth()->user()->company_id ?? 0) : 0;
    $log['created_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    LogActivityModel::create($log);
}
```

Comment: You should add context, explanation, and documentation links to your answers to make them more useful. Code-only answers are not helpful.

Comment: sure, I must target only the company_id index in the code